# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed - mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I have two tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
`email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`username` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`website` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`facebook_id` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`google_id` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`provider` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`getUpdates` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`id` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
`createdAt` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updatedAt` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `email` (`email`)
)
COLLATE='hebrew_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I get the error trying to create the other one:

```
CREATE TABLE `userfilescategories` (
`name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`user` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`createdAt` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updatedAt` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `user` (`user`),
CONSTRAINT `UserFilesCategories_Users_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES   `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
```

The error I get is :

```
SQL Error (1005): Can't create table 'ev.userfilescategries' (errno:150)
Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed
```

From Show Engine InnoDB status I get:

```
Error in foreign key constraint of table ev/userfilescategories:
FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6:
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint. 
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
```

What do I miss? How can it be that the foreign key is incorrectly formed?

Comment: Can you post the error message that you are receiving?

Comment: Run `show engine innodb status` for the exact error message. You may need to run the query as root.

Comment: I added the error I get

Comment: Your error message tell 'ev.userfilescategries', but your table name is 'userfilescategories'. Are you sure that the script posted is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create these two tables having the same **COLLATE (utf8_general_ci)**

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
`email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`username` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`website` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`facebook_id` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`google_id` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`provider` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`getUpdates` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`createdAt` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updatedAt` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `email` (`email`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `userfilescategories` (
`name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`user` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`createdAt` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updatedAt` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `user` (`user`),
CONSTRAINT `UserFilesCategories_Users_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES   `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
```

**N:B:** Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same.

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the job, can't believe i missed that

Comment: You are most welcome.Glad to know that worked for you. By the way, anyone can miss that. :p